# How to drag and release an object with velocity

Tags: swift, touch, sprite-kit

I'm working with Xcode, using swift, and I'd like to be able to touch a ball with my finger, drag it around the screen, and then when I pick up my finger, it should maintain the velocity it had during the drag. I've tried recording the last 5 positions of the touch in an array, and then calculating the velocity from the difference in position between the ball's current location and where it was five frames ago, but it frequently shoots off at odd angles and speeds. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dragging and releasing a sprite with velocity can be accomplished by

First, a `struct` to store touch data

```
struct TouchInfo {
    var location:CGPoint
    var time:NSTimeInterval
}
```

Declare `SKScene` subclass properties

```
var selectedNode:SKSpriteNode?
var history:[TouchInfo]?
```

In `touchesBegan`

1. Save the sprite that the user touched
2. Save touch event data

Swift code:

```
let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
if (node.name == "player") {
    // Step 1
    selectedNode = node as? SKSpriteNode;
    // Stop the sprite
    selectedNode?.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0)
    // Step 2: save information about the touch
    history = [TouchInfo(location:location, time:touch.timestamp)]
}
```

In `touchesMoved`

1. If a sprite was selected in touchesBegan, move the sprite to the new location
2. Save the touch event data

Swift code:

```
let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
if (selectedNode != nil) {
    // Step 1. update sprite's position
    selectedNode?.position = location
    // Step 2. save touch data at index 0
    history?.insert(TouchInfo(location:location, time:touch.timestamp),atIndex:0)
}
```

In `touchesEnded`

1. Calculate the differences in x and y from the last touch and the current touch
2. Find the time difference between touch events
3. Calculate and keep a sum of the velocity components in x and y
4. Create a velocity vector and apply it to the sprite
5. Unselect the node

Swift code:

```
if let history = history, history.count > 1 && selectedNode != nil {
    var vx:CGFloat = 0.0
    var vy:CGFloat = 0.0
    var previousTouchInfo:TouchInfo?
    // Adjust this value as needed
    let maxIterations = 3
    var numElts:Int = min(history.count, maxIterations)
    // Loop over touch history
    for index in 0..<numElts {
        let touchInfo = history[index]
        let location = touchInfo.location
        if let previousTouch = previousTouchInfo {
            // Step 1
            let dx = location.x - previousTouch.location.x
            let dy = location.y - previousTouch.location.y
            // Step 2
            let dt = CGFloat(touchInfo.time - previousTouch.time)
            // Step 3
            vx += dx / dt
            vy += dy / dt
        }
        previousTouchInfo = touchInfo
    }
    let count = CGFloat(numElts-1)
    // Step 4
    let velocity = CGVectorMake(vx/count,vy/count)
    selectedNode?.physicsBody?.velocity = velocity
}
// Step 5
selectedNode = nil
history = nil
```

Comment: It says that 'previousTime' is an unresolved identifier. Where and how should I declare it?

Comment: `previousTime` should be `previousTouchInfo!.time`. I updated my answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. It looks like it works pretty well now, it's much smoother than it was before.

Comment: Actually, there's still one problem. If I tap and let go without dragging, the program crashes.

Comment: I fixed the issue by updating the `if` statement in `touchesEnded`.

Comment: @0x141E this looks like a great solution. Would you have any idea why touchesEnded would have no effect? I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure what you mean by "have no effect." Is `touchedEnded` being called?

Comment: @0x141E Thanks for your reply. I mean when I release the tap it doesn't "slide". So it is getting called.

Comment: @Tim did you add a physics body to the sprite?

Comment: @0x141E Very simple fix after all - thank you for your help.

Comment: @0x141E Just revisiting this - simply tapping the view without moving it breaks the program. The line `let touchInfo = history![index]` displays error 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range'. Any ideas?